# Get regex rules for a capture group

Tags: javascript, regex

I am looking for a method to get the regex *rules*, for a capture group.

So if I had: `/(\w) (\d)/` I would want `$1 = /\w/` and `$2 = /\d/`.

Is there a method for this?

Comment: What are `$1` and `$2`? What do you mean by RegEx rules?

Comment: it does the same thing.

Comment: @thefourtheye I think he is wanting `var group1rg = '\w'` and so on, based  on the regex.

Comment: @thefourtheye `$1` and `$2` are backreferences, but everything thing I can find talks about naming `$1`. I don't really care what it is named.

Comment: @amit-joki, yes, that is exactly what I want.

Comment: @BrandonPoe is an extra `)` in your regex intentional?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided that the regex is valid and no nested groups are used, then you can try this out.

```
var arr = (regex + "").match(/\(.*?\)/g).map(function(rule){
   return rule.replace(/[()]/g, "");
});
```

Now, `arr[0]` will have rule of group1, `arr[1]` will be group2 and so on.

Comment: I wish javascript had a method to do this, but this does the trick. Thanks!

Comment: @BrandonPoe glad to have helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't know of any direct way to do this on a regex rule given by `/(rule1)(rule2)/` you could build the regex rule using strings and specify your grouping in different strings.

```
var group1 = '([A-Za-z]+)',
group2 = '(\\d+)',
r = new RegExp(group1+group2);
r.test('hello1234');
```

To get the groups from a regex string you could run a regex on that regex string to extract the groups. If your regex string is `"(\w+)(\d+)"` then you'd have a regex to extract the groups as `/(\([^\)\))+/`

Comment: The original regex would be a string that I would want to break apart, so this wouldn't do the trick. Thanks though.

Comment: Updated the answer, hope that helps.